# Detection table as a surface gives a lot of rectangles

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I want to get a rectangle of the surface of a table. So I thought I can do this with opencv with the findContours and contourArea function. Now when the result is when I take the max contourArea that it takes everything as an area. When I don't do that it gives a different result see pictures.

[image: Green rectangle over the whole image]

[image: Rectangles everywhere]

Is there a way to combine the rectangles so that it detects the table as a surface? Because I want to know if those things are on the surface or are moved away from the surface.

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

file = "/Users/mars/Downloads/table.jpg"

im1 = cv2.imread(file, 0)
im = cv2.imread(file)

ret, thresh_value = cv2.threshold(im1, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
dilated_value = cv2.dilate(thresh_value, kernel, iterations=1)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated_value, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
max_index = np.argmax(areas)
cnt = contours[max_index]
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', im)
```

Comment: Try to increase kernel size `kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason your code is not working is because you are using `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV`.
Inverting polarity, turns the table area to black color, and `findContours` is searching for white contours.

I suggest using the following stages:

- Convert to binary image - use `THRESH_OTSU` for automatic threshold (it's more robust than using fixed threshold).
- Use "closing" morphological operation (closing is like dilate and than erode).
  closing is better than `dilate`, because it doesn't change the size of the contour.
- Find contours, use `RETR_EXTERNAL` instead of `RETR_TREE`, because you are looking for the external contour.
- Find contour with maximum area.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Read input image
im = cv2.imread('table.jpg')

# Drop one row and column from each side (because the image you posted has a green rectangle around it).
im = im[1:-2, 1:-2, :]

# Convert to Grayscale
im1 = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Convert to binary image - use THRESH_OTSU for automatic threshold.
ret, thresh_value = cv2.threshold(im1, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Use "closing" morphological operation (closing is like dilate and than erode)
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh_value, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((5, 5)))

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]  # [-2] indexing is used due to OpenCV compatibility issues.

# Get contour with maximum area
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Mark contour with green line
cv2.drawContours(im, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)


# Show output
cv2.imshow('im', cv2.resize(im, (im.shape[1]//4, im.shape[0]//4)))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the demo code and the explanation. It works perfect!